# ReactJS property timerID does not exist on type Clock

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im new in react js, and currently Im trying to follow official reactjs documentation, running some examples.
Recently I tried this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

But when I put this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Clock extends React.Component {

    state = {
        date: new Date()
    };

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        this.timerID = 0;
    }    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(),
            1000
        );
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
      }

      tick() {
        this.setState({
          date: new Date()
        });
      }           
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

But in componentDidMount() function I get this error:

> property timerID does not exist on type Clock

Im not sure what is wrong here, I tried to declare timerID near state declaration, but it causes other errors, so I wonder what Im doing wrong. Btw this is ionic framework project, not sure if this can be a cause of an error.

These are my dependencies in package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@ionic/react": "^4.8.0-rc.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^4.8.0-rc.0",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "11.11.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "ionicons": "^4.6.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is coming from typescript and not from React, add `timerID` to the class properties

You will need to use `window.setInterval` and not `setInterval` alone because it will type it as `NodeJS.Timeout`

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
    timerID: number;

    state = {
        date: new Date()
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = window.setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! One more question, why window.setInterval works fine while setInterval shows Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: I wonder why official reactjs documentation code does not work in my environment.

Comment: @Scoracle Because `Node` and the browser both have `setInterval` functions which return different types so you have to specify that you use the one from the browser and not `Node`

Comment: @Scoracle It's because you use typescript which requires additional code to work such as typing props state etc... I think if you just starting with React you should follow the tutorial using javascript and after you should learn how to integrate it with typescript

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare `timerID` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.timerID = 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed my constructor as you said, but still get the same error, in this line: this.timerID = 0; and in other places where I use timerID

Comment: The issue was also related to the type used. Glad you could solve it with AsafAviv help. As he suggests dig into TypeScript once you feel comfortable enough with React.